# Multitasking while UFT run

Tags: hp-uft

I would like to work on other applications when UFT is running on an application. Presently I don't see any option like this, is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little bit better?

Comment: You can work on other applications while running UFT but then there is a good chance that your scripts will fail if you are interacting with the GUI. The only viable option is what @Motti wrote in his answer - VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some applications (typically windows based) UFT takes control of the mouse and keyboard which interferes with normal work on the computer. For most technologies this is not an issue since UFT does not interfere with the input devices. If possible it's always better not to work on the computer that's running tests, you can install UFT on a virtual machine and continue working on your physical machine.